# JS Как сделать кнопку удаления активной/неактивной при добавлении строк в таблицу?

Tags: javascript, html

Если все строки в таблице удалены, кнопка удаления должна быть неактивна, при добавлении строки кнопка вновь должна стать активной для удаления.  Первое условие выполняется и кнопка становится disabled, но при добавлении строк она все еще отключена, как это можно исправить?

```js
function deleteRow() {
   tg.deleteRow(3);
   if (document.all("tg").rows.length < 5) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled=true;
   }
   else if(document.all("tg").rows.length > 5) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled=false;
   }
  }
```

```html
<button id="b" onClick="deleteRow(); return false;">Удалить</button>
```

Comment: А при добавлении то проверку вызываете? И у вас интересное условие: делать кнопку disabled, когда длина < 5 (т.е. 4 и меньше), и делать кнопку активной, когда строк > 5 (т.е. 6 и выше). Может, надо _>=_ 5?

Comment: хоть бы добавления сроки описали

Comment: да, вы правы, >= 5 более корректно, что касаемо проверки - как ее совершить?
добавление строки вполне себе стандартное: var row = document.createElement("TR")
var tbody = document.getElementById("tg").insertRow(3);
var r1=tbody.insertCell(0);
r1.innerHTML=""; и т.д
<button id="a" onClick="addRow();return false;" >Добавить</button>

Comment: @Dany написанный Вами код, по идее, должен быть обернут в функцию. В конце выполнения функции (после того, как строка уже добавлена) вызывайте проверку длины с тем же условием - если >= 5, то разлочить кнопку. А еще лучше - создайте отдельную функцию, назовите ее toggleDeleteBtn - она будет возвращать необходимое состояние кнопки. Либо disabled, либо нет

Comment: так что мешает добавить в функцию addRow в конце ?
document.getElementById("b").disabled=false;

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Накидал в ответы пример, а вы уже и решили проблему =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерный шаблон такой (собрал из кусков Вашего кода):

```
function addRow() {
  var row = document.createElement("TR");
  var tbody = document.getElementById("tg").insertRow(3);
  var r1=tbody.insertCell(0);
  r1.innerHTML="";
  toggleDeleteBtn();
}

toggleDeleteButton() {
  if (document.all("tg").rows.length < 5) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled=true;
  } else if(document.all("tg").rows.length >= 5) {
    document.getElementById("b").disabled=false;
  }
}

function deleteRow() {
  //... Delete row function body
}

<button id="a" onClick="addRow();return false;" >Добавить</button>
<button id="b" onClick="deleteRow(); return false;">Удалить</button>
```

Включение/отключение/применение различных стилей для элементов лучше всегда выносить в отдельную функцию. В данном случае в отдельную функцию вынесен функционал по добавлению/отключению атрибута disabled для кнопки

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.parentElOfList').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
      if (document.all("tg").rows.length < 5) {
            document.getElementById("b").disabled=true;
        }
        else if(document.all("tg").rows.length > 5) {
            document.getElementById("b").disabled=false;
        }
 });
```